# Aspose.Cells - ErrorCheckOptions

Tags: vb.net, error-checking

```
Dim opts As ErrorCheckOptionCollection = workBook.Worksheets(0).ErrorCheckOptions
Dim index As Integer = opts.Add()
Dim opt As ErrorCheckOption = opts(index)
opt.SetErrorCheck(ErrorCheckType.TextNumber, False)
```

Above the Code, which is used to disable `ErrorCheckOption` in Excel, but during run-time it is still retaining as enabled. once the excel sheet is downloaded, if we double click on cell, cell is appearing with green color (i.e text format) 
Can you please suggest for any alternative.
I have attached screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to specify your desired range of cells/ area for error checking option(s) to be set in the worksheet:
e.g
opt.AddRange(CellArea.CreateCellArea(0, 0, 1000, 50))

I am a developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.